# Regular expression for templating captures too much

Tags: php, regex, templates

With PHP I'm trying to get my regular expression to match both template references below. The problem is, it also grabs the `</ul>` from the first block of text. When I remove the `/s` flag that it only catches the second reference. What I'm a doing wrong?

```
/{{\%USERS}}(.*)?{{\%\/USERS}}/s
```

Here is my string.

```
<ul class="users">
{{%USERS}}
<li>{%}</li>
{{%/USERS}}
</ul>

{{%USERS}} hello?!{{%/USERS}}
```

Why is my expression catching too much or too little?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Why is my expression catching too much or too little?

1. Its catching too much because the quantifiers are greedy by default (see Li-aung Yip answer +1 for that)
2. If you remove the modifier `s` it matches only the second occurrence, because that modifier makes the `.` also match newline characters, so without it, it's not possible to match the first part, because there are newlines in between.

See the non greedy answer

```
{{\%USERS}}(.*?){{\%\/USERS}}
```

[here on Regexr](http://regexr.com?30rj7), a good place to test regular expressions.

Btw. I removed the `?` after the capturing group, its not needed, since `*` matches also the empty string, so no need to make it additionally optional.

Comment: I didn't know regex was greedy by default, good to know! I could have sworn I tried that and it didn't work, but I think it's because I didn't include the dotall flag.

Answer (score 2):

You probably need to use non-greedy quantifiers.

`*` and `+` are "greedy". They'll match as many characters as they can.

`*?` and `+?` are "non-greedy". They'll match only as many characters as required to move on to the next part of the regex.

So in the following test string:

```
<alpha><bravo>
```

- `<.+>` will capture `<alpha><bravo>` (because `.` matches `><` as
  well!).
- `<.+?>` will capture `<alpha>`.

Answer (score 0):

Here is your regexp:

```
/{{%USERS}}([^{]+({%[^{]+)?){{%/USERS}}/g
```

Comment: [It works](http://regexr.com?30riu), but you should really explain *why* it works. (Also it breaks for `{{%USERS}} {asdf} {{%/USERS}}` or `{{%USERS}}{{%/USERS}}`.)

Comment: I've created regex due to string provided by author. There was no comments about string contents

Comment: Sure, but as competent programmers, it's out duty to code defensively at all times. ;)

Comment: There is no `g` modifier in php, it uses `preg_match` to get the first match and `preg_match_all` the get all matches.

Comment: I tried lots of different combos and get close, but then they don't capture everything in between, which is the problem with the one above.

Comment: RegEx's break because of difeerent content in between `{{%USERS}}` and  `{{%/USERS}}`. Give us what could possibly be inside those tags. All possibilities please